# NoClassDefFoundError when importing Tika 1.13 in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, apache-tika

I've done the following steps per the tika guide:

1. Add the tika-core and tika-parser dependencies to the pom.xml of the maven project

   2. Run maven install from eclipse to produce tika-core jar and tika-parser jar
   3. Add tika-core jar and tika-parser jar to my eclipse project build path

And I get this runtime exception when trying to run tika:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.InvalidPasswordException
    at com.ibm.hrl.ace.pdftotext.TikaExtracter.parse(TikaExtracter.java:33)
    at com.ibm.hrl.ace.pdftotext.Main.AllPdfsToText(Main.java:116)
    at com.ibm.hrl.ace.pdftotext.Main.main(Main.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.InvalidPasswordException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:600)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:786)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:326)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:741)
    ... 3 more
```

As far as I can see, when I build the jars using maven, it does add pdfbox properly... from the build log:

```
[INFO] Including org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:jar:2.0.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.pdfbox:fontbox:jar:2.0.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox-tools:jar:2.0.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox-debugger:jar:2.0.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.pdfbox:jempbox:jar:1.8.12 in the shaded jar.
```

And here are my maven dependencies:

```
  <dependencies>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tika/tika-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.13</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tika/tika-parsers -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
    <version>1.13</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: but are the jar files in your class path at runtime? (Maybe mention: Are you running tika from within eclipse or outside (with java -jar ...)?)

Comment: Why did you call mvn install for tika core and parsers? They are available on the repo, so you don't have to build them.

Comment: I'm running tika from within eclipse after adding the two jars to the build path like in the tika instructions. Inside the project that built the jars, I do see the pdfbox package with the needed InvalidPasswordException class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that if you manually add tika-core and tika-parsers jars in your build path you will not have the transitive dependencies that are listed in their own POM.

So I would suggest to:

1. Remove the tika-core and tika-parsers version that you have built yourself. Instead you should rely on the versions that are available on central. This will ensure that another one building your project will get the same jar (and not a locally built one)
2. You have two options

(Option A, use Maven) Do not add manually into Eclipse build path the jars. Rely either or built-in Maven plugin for Eclipse (m2e for instance) or use Eclipse plugin for maven (call mvn eclipse:eclipse to update .classpath and .project).

(Option B, without Maven) If you cannot use Maven for your project, you will have to add not only tika-parsers and tika-core jars, but all (most of) the transitive dependencies needed by these project (including for instance specific library per format [POI for Office, pdfbox for PDF...). You can get a list of the dependencies by typing `mvn dependency:list` in the folder containing the pom of tika-parsers.

Comment: Hi, option 2 is not available to me because I can't use Maven on this project. I did option 1 (downloaded the appropriate jars -core and -parsers from the maven central repository) and the same problem persisted. How do I build the jars to include all the necessary libraries?

Comment: Without Maven option added